# NSPredicate with array of NSNumbers

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate, nsnumber

I have an array of `NSNumber`s, for example: 10015, 12313, 10016

I want to check if the array contains the integer I've entered in the searchBar.

My code:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %d", [searchText intValue]];


self.searchResults = [newArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you need is the boolean value of whether the array contains it then you want.

```
self.searchResults = [newArr containsObject:@([searchText intValue])];
```

If you actually want a subset of `NSNumber`s in the results (in this case 1), then contains will not work.  Have to check equality of the value of each `NSNumber` like this...

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %d", [searchText intValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know if the number is in the array, there's no need to use predicates:

```
BOOL occurs = [newArr containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[searchText intValue]]];
```

should do it.

Comment: This won't work as-is since you need to pass an object, not an `int`. Try this as `[newArr containsObject:@([searchText intValue])];`. This will wrap the `int` in an `NSNumber`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! Should really try to compile my sample code before posting.